# How to Fix Some Portion of bound camera?

Tags: android, game-design, andengine

I want to add Progress bar with my game to display life of player but when i move down through DigitalOnScreen Control the black bar that i want to display is not displayed there. I want to display that bar when i move in any direction it should be constantly displayed  [image: Here progress bar as a image is displayed]
        [image: Here Progress bar is not displayed]

Comment: Usually, GUI items don't have a position in the world, rather just one in the camera space. a little more information about your actual code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HUD.when move your camera, hud is not move that stable.

```
HUD hud = new HUD();
yourCamera.setHUD(hud);

hud.attachChild(yourBar);

public class GameTest extends BaseGameActivity {
private Camera camera;
private Scene scene;
private HUD hud;

@Override
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
    camera = new Camera(0, 0, Helper.CAMERA_WIDTH, Helper.CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true,
            ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT, new RatioResolutionPolicy(
                    Helper.CAMERA_WIDTH, Helper.CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    return new Engine(engineOptions);
}

@Override
public void onLoadResources() {
}

@Override
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    scene = new Scene();
    hud = new HUD();
    camera.setHUD(hud);

    Sprite blackBar = new Sprite(posX, posY, yourRegion);
    hud.attachChild(blackBar);

    return scene;
}

@Override
public void onLoadComplete() {
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer But i am using Scene so i don't know how to use HUD with Scene.

Comment: @Maan hud is one of Entity like scene. You can attach or detach entity in hud.

also i update my code it helpful you.